# What is the syntax to define variable in properties file when using Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am deploying my application package to tomcat docker image and there is a properties files as part of the package that is to configure the MQ and database details. The database is in a different VM and not in a docker. I want to pass the MQ and database details while running the container through env file.

I have defined variable in application.properties as below,
application.properties :

```
service.jms.provider.url=tcp://${MQ_SERVER}:${MQ_PORT}

#oracle

jdbc.driverClassName=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
jdbc.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@${DB_HOST}:${DB_PORT}/${DB_SID}
jdbc.username=${DB_SCHEMA}
jdbc.defaultSchema=${DB_SCHEMA}
jdbc.password=${DB_SCHEMA_PASSWORD}
```

I have defined the env file as  :

```
###Ports
MQ_SERVER=19.16.960.1
MQ_PORT=61616


#DB details
DB_HOST=19.16.960.1
DB_PORT=1521
DB_SID=DEV
DB_SCHEMA=DEV1
DB_SCHEMA_PASSWORD=DJ4bk5YcypeiFjTtxb2YWTIa+8gWHE3I=
```

I run docker image with the command

```
docker run -p 8081:8080 --env-file=.env --name dev-d dev
```

When running the command 'set' inside the container , is see that the variables are displayed correctly with it value. But get the below error

1. I get the below error :

-failed to decrypt resolved value: value=${DB_SCHEMA_PASSWORD} {com.misys.tools.integration.utils.ResolveDecryptTextUtil:45}

what is the right format to define the variable in the application.properties and how can I check the value has been picked

Comment: Try adding quotation marks around the password in the env file.

Comment: @MarkoE, should it be a double quote or single quote? Should it be defined inside the properties file ? example , "${DB_SCHEMA_PASSWORD}" or '${DB_SCHEMA_PASSWORD}'

Comment: yes, sorry, `jdbc.password="${DB_SCHEMA_PASSWORD}"`, so in the `application.properties` file. My bad!

Comment: @MarkoE, I get the same error when trying the solution you have recommended... any other way ?